# How to read from a variable having varying character length from in-stream data in SAS?

Tags: sas

Hopefully a easy one.
I am fairly new to SAS.

I am trying to read data using following SAS code (as per given in lecture notes), but it is not producing proper SAS dataset because of some character length issue. I tried : and & some hit and trial but not able to fix it. Can anyone kindly explain me on how can I fix this?

```
data SMSA_subset_weather;
length city $ 27;
input city & JanTemp JulyTemp RelHum Rain; 
datalines; 
Akron, OH 27 71 59 36 
Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY 23 72 57 35 
Baltimore, MD 35 77 55 43 
Allentown, Bethlehem, PA-NJ 29 74 54 44 
Atlanta, GA 45 79 56 47 
;
run
;
```

[image]
I am using SAS ON DEMAND. When I use dsd it is giving me the desired output, like below:

```
data SMSA_subset_weather;
infile datalines delimiter=" " dsd;
length city $ 27;
input city & JanTemp JulyTemp RelHum Rain; 
datalines; 
"Akron, OH" 27 71 59 36 
"Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY" 23 72 57 35 
"Baltimore, MD" 35 77 55 43 
"Allentown, Bethlehem, PA-NJ" 29 74 54 44 
"Atlanta, GA" 45 79 56 47 
;
run
;
```

[image]
I am achieving this by modifying the instream data and using dsd option. But I assume I cant handle if there were more of such observations.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second space following the city name, or quotation marks.

When using a delimiter that may appear in the data, you can use the `&` as you do in order to ask SAS to read until it finds two consecutive delimiters.  (You also can use `DSD` option and quotation marks.)

So here:

```
data SMSA_subset_weather;
length city $ 27;
input city & JanTemp JulyTemp RelHum Rain; 
datalines; 
Akron, OH  27 71 59 36 
Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY  23 72 57 35 
Baltimore, MD  35 77 55 43 
Allentown, Bethlehem, PA-NJ  29 74 54 44 
Atlanta, GA  45 79 56 47 
;
run
;
```

Or here, using DSD with quotation marks:

```
data SMSA_subset_weather;
length city $ 27;
infile datalines dsd dlm=' ';
input city JanTemp JulyTemp RelHum Rain; 
datalines; 
"Akron, OH" 27 71 59 36 
"Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY" 23 72 57 35 
"Baltimore, MD" 35 77 55 43 
"Allentown, Bethlehem, PA-NJ" 29 74 54 44 
"Atlanta, GA" 45 79 56 47 
;
run
;
```

Comment: Looks like both the methods (1) "dsd" and (2) "&" worked. I think in the lecture notes the spaces might have got omitted or something bizarre I assume such that it was n't working for me. Anyways thanks for the quick help Joe. Much appreciated.